# Rainy dark day or dark rainy day

Tags: adjective-order

There is a part showing adjective order in English Grammar In Use 5th edition p.198 and it doesn't help me to get to know which one is correct; 'rainy dark day' or 'dark rainy day'. The section in Cambridge Dictionary [1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/dilbilgisi/ingiliz-dilbilgisi/adjectives-order) doesn't help either as I'm not sure if 'rainy' a physical quality. Which one is correct, 'rainy dark day' or 'dark rainy day'?

Note: 'Dark' is not used in figurative meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"A dark, rainy day" is correct.

"Dark" falls under the "colour" category.

"Rainy" doesn't fall under any category I usually see in adjective order lists, but I dug a bit and found [this list of adjective order](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) from Cambridge, which includes the category "type". I'd say "rainy" is a type of day, and "a dark, rainy day" is certainly the correct order.